# Issues uncompressing a tar.gz file

Tags: java, gzip, tar, compression

I have been trying to uncompress the following file:

```
sudo wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u21-b11/jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

with the following:

```
sudo tar zxvf jdk-7u21-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/
```

I am getting this error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I am using an Amazon Linux instances. By default jre is installed instead of the jdk, which I need to be able to run jboss. I would install the jdk using `yum`, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible. Issue I am having is that it doesn't make sense why its not working if I am doing everything right from what I have been able to discern. I have downloaded two different versions just to be sure its not just corrupted files. Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The reason the file isn't extracting properly is because the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) is setting a cookie when you accept the license agreement. If you don't have the session cookie when attempting to download the file, it redirects you to an HTML page that tells you to accept the agreement first. If you open the .tar.gz that you're getting from `wget`, you'll see that it's an HTML file since it's not getting said cookie.

The easiest way to solve it is to download the file first, using your web browser, and then upload it to your web server.

Answer (score 40):

I know this thread is old, but I figured someone might be able to use this information when searching the web for why they can't unzip their JDK distros on raspberrypi

If you pass these parameters to wget it will also accept the policy.

```
--no-cookies --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"
```

Comment: Very interesting. That'll be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Still a valid answer in 2016. Thank you for this one !

Comment: This is a very hidden fact.  Oracle should make it easier for us to **wget** the jdk, especially on RaspberryPi.  Thanks!

Comment: Works in 2018!!

Comment: Not available anymore in 2020 :(

Answer (score 6):

j883376 answer is right.But 
The easiest way to solve it is to download the file first, using your web browser, and then copy the download url then wget it useing  your  server.